# Error "index out of range" when working with strings in a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, runtime-error

I'm very new to python and I'm practicing different exercises.

I need to write a program to `decode` a string. The original string has been modified by adding, after each vowel (letters ’a’, ’e’, ’i’, ’o’ and ’u’), the letter `’p’` and then that same vowel again.
For example, the word `“kemija”` becomes `“kepemipijapa”` and the word `“paprika”` becomes `“papapripikapa”`.

```
 vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
 input_word = list(input())

 for i in range(len(input_word)):
     if input_word[i] in vowel:
         input_word.pop(i + 1)
         input_word.pop(i + 2)

 print(input_word)
```

The algorithm I had in mind was to detect the index for which the item is a vowel and then remove the following 2 items after this item ,so if `input_word[0] == 'e'` then the next 2 items `(input_word[1], input_word[2])` must be removed from the list. For the sample input `zepelepenapa`, I get this error message : `IndexError: pop index out of range` even when I change the for loop to `range(len(input_word) - 2)` ,again I get this same error.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will run a number of times equal to the original length of `input_word`, due to `range(len(input_word))`. An `IndexError` will occur if `input_word` is shortened inside the loop, because the code inside the loop tries to access every element in the original list `input_word` with  the expression `input_word[i]` (and, for some values of `input_word`, the `if` block could even attempt to pop items off the list beyond its original length, due to the `(i + 1)` and `(i + 2)`).

Hardcoding the loop definition with a specific number like `2`, e.g. with `range(len(input_word) - 2)`, to make it run fewer times to account for removed letters isn't a general solution, because the number of letters to be removed is initially unknown (it could be 0, 2, 4, ...).

Here are a couple of possible solutions:

1. Instead of removing items from `input_word`, create a new list `output_word` and add letters to it if they meet the criteria.  Use a helper list `skip_these_indices` to keep track of indices that should be "removed" from `input_word` so they can be skipped when building up the new list `output_word`:

```py
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
input_word = list("zepelepenapa")
output_word = []
skip_these_indices = []

for i in range(len(input_word)):

    # if letter 'i' shouldn't be skipped, add it to output_word
    if i not in skip_these_indices:
        output_word.append(input_word[i])

        # check whether to skip the next two letters after 'i'
        if input_word[i] in vowel:
            skip_these_indices.append(i + 1)
            skip_these_indices.append(i + 2)

print(skip_these_indices)       # [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11]
print(output_word)              # ['z', 'e', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'a']
print(''.join(output_word))     # zelena
```

2. Alternatively, use two loops.  The first loop will keep track of which letters should be removed in a list called `remove_these_indices`.  The second loop will remove them from `input_word`:

```py
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
input_word = list("zepelepenapa")
remove_these_indices = []

# loop 1 -- find letters to remove
for i in range(len(input_word)):

    # if letter 'i' isn't already marked for removal,
    # check whether we should remove the next two letters
    if i not in remove_these_indices:
        if input_word[i] in vowel:
            remove_these_indices.append(i + 1)
            remove_these_indices.append(i + 2)

# loop 2 -- remove the letters (pop in reverse to avoid IndexError)
for i in reversed(remove_these_indices):

    # if input_word has a vowel in the last two positions,
    # without a "p" and the same vowel after it,
    # which it shouldn't based on the algorithm you
    # described for generating the coded word,
    # this 'if' statement will avoid popping
    # elements that don't exist
    if i < len(input_word):
        input_word.pop(i)

print(remove_these_indices) # [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11]
print(input_word)           # ['z', 'e', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'a']
print(''.join(input_word))  # zelena
```

Answer (score 1):

`pop()` removes an item at the given position in the list and returns it. This alters the list in place.

For example if I have:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
n = my_list.pop()
```

will return `n = 4` in this instance. If I was to print `my_list` after this operation it would return `[1,2,3]`. So the length of the list will change every time `pop()` is used. That is why you are getting `IndexError: pop index out of range`.

So to solve this we should avoid using pop() since it's really not needed in this situation. The following will work:

```
word = 'kemija'
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    
new_word = []
    
for w in word:
    if w in vowels:
        new_word.extend([w,'p',w])
        # alternatively you could use .append() over .extend() but would need more lines: 
        # new_word.append(w)
        # new_word.append('p')
        # new_word.append(w)
    else:
        new_word.append(w)
    
decoded_word = ''.join(new_word)
print(decoded_word)
```